# Working with a remainder of Zero with modulo operation?

Tags: python

I'm having some difficulty working with a remainder of zero with the modulo operator.

Basically this is a line of my code

```
fday= (day+24) % 30
```

I'm trying to just add 24 to any day and take the remainder of it. However, if a user enters 6 for the day, the result is zero which I don't want.

How can I make the operation return 6 if 6 is entered? Is there a better way to do this?

**Update:**

I'm trying to take a previously defined variable (`day`) and add 24 days to that value.

However if a user enters the 25th day of the month, and then I add 24 to it I get 49, but 49 days arent in a month.

That's why I'm trying to use the modulo operation to give me the remainder instead, because it works for the 30 days in one month thing.

Another example:

If 5 was input, it would be 5 +24 which is 29 and then `29%30 = 29`. So 5 works for what I'm trying to do (which is to just add 24 days to the value and still keep the output under 30 (because there are only 30 days in a month for the purposes of what I'm doing).

Comment: Can you  give  a few more example inputs and desired outputs for those inputs? I can't really understand what you want from your question.

Comment: Well basically im trying to take a previously defined variable (day) and add 24 days to that value.. however if a user enters the 25th day of the month, and then i add 24 to it. ill get 49, but 49 days arent in a month, thats why im trying to use the modulo operation to give me the remainder instead, because it works for the 30 days in one month thing.

Comment: @pythonnoob: Then I don't understand why an input of 6 should give an output of 6. What should inputs 5 and 7 give?

Comment: Okay, so if 5 was input, it would be 5 +24 which is 29 and then 29%30= 29 . So 5 works for what im trying to do (which is to just add 24 days to the value and still keep the output under 30 (because im  there are only 30 days in a month for the purposes of what im doing)

Comment: @pythonnoob: So what should 7 give?

Comment: 1 (which is the first of the next month in my context)

Comment: pythonoob -- you don't want `6` for `6`, you want `30`, because the 6th day plus 24 days is the 30th day of the month, __not__ the 6th day. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You say in the comments that for `5` you want `29`, for `6` you want `6`, and for `7` you want `1`. That doesn't make sense. The correct value for `6` is `30` not `6` or `0` when you're calculating a day modulo `30`.

In math, division by `30` gives a remainder between `0` and `29` -- that's what modulo `30` is. What *you* want is a number between `1` and `30`.

So you need to take the day, **subtract `1`** (to get a day between `0` and `29` instead of `1` and `30`), add `24`, then do the modulo `30`, then **add `1`** (to get back a day between `1` and `30`.

```
result = ((day - 1 + 24) % 30) + 1
```

That way you'll always get the correct number between `1` and `30` and you don't have to think of `6` as a special case.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the functionality in the `datetime` module instead of trying to reinvent it:

```
>>> from datetime import date, timedelta
>>> for month in (4, 5):
...     for day in (5, 6, 7, 8):
...         start = date(2011, month, day)
...         later = start + timedelta(days=24)
...         print str(start), str(later)
...
2011-04-05 2011-04-29
2011-04-06 2011-04-30
2011-04-07 2011-05-01
2011-04-08 2011-05-02
2011-05-05 2011-05-29
2011-05-06 2011-05-30
2011-05-07 2011-05-31
2011-05-08 2011-06-01
```